# Python json decode and parsing data

Tags: python, json

I have managed to get the json data from a API and pull the section I needed. I wanted to parse just the public url section only as the output. This is my code:

```
import json
import httplib as client
headers = {"Content-type": "application/json"}
params = json.dumps({"auth": {"passwordCredentials": {"username": "myusername",         "password": "mypassword"}}})
conn = client.HTTPSConnection("lon.identity.api.rackspacecloud.com:443")
conn.request("POST", "/v2.0/tokens", params, headers)
response = conn.getresponse()
output = response.read()
data = json.loads(output)
token = data['access']['serviceCatalog']
print(token)
```

This is the output data:

```
[{"endpoints": [{"region": "LON","publicURL": "https://storage101.lon3.clouddrive.com/v1/MossoCloudFS_bfe4a309-40cf-49b8-acd0-d15f4865542f3","internalURL": "https://snet-storage101.lon3.clouddrive.com/v1/MossoCloudFS_bfe4a309-40cf-49b8-acd0-d15f48vdwds3","tenantId": "MossoCloudFS_bfe4a309-40cf-49b8-acd0-d15f486e82f3"}],"type": "object-store","name": "cloudFiles"}]
```

Now in my code I have tried:

```
token = data['access']['serviceCatalog']['endpoints']['publicURL']
```

However I get: TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str

How can I parse the publicURL?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`data['access']['serviceCatalog']` doesn't contain a dict directly, but instead a list whose sole element is a dict. Similarly the `endpoints` dict's value is a list whose sole member is a dict. Try this instead:

```
token = data['access']['serviceCatalog'][0]['endpoints'][0]['publicURL']
```

Answering the question from the comment below, if there are multiple endpoints you can use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to get all the public URLs.

```
urls = [x['endpoints'][0]['publicURL'] for x in data['access']['serviceCatalog']]
```

Comment: Great! Thank you for you quick response. Another question if you do not mind. The output gives various endpoints. How came I parse just all the publicURLs of the endpoints?

Answer (score 0):

data is a list (with one element which happens to be a dictionary), but you are trying to use it like a dictionary.

```
>>> type(data)
<class 'list'>
```

Try

```
data = data[0]

>>> type(data)
<class 'dict'>
```

Answer (score 0):

The output data is a array, you need access to that data with a index.

In this case is:

```
token = data[0][xxx][xxx]
```

Though with the output data, the correct syntax for access to data of "publicURL" is:

```
data[0]["endpoints"][0]["publicURL"]
```

Example:

```
>>> data = [{"endpoints": [{"region": "LON","publicURL": "https://storage101.lon3.clouddrive.com/v1/MossoCloudFS_bfe4a309-40cf-49b8-acd0-d15f4865542f3","internalURL": "https://snet-storage101.lon3.clouddrive.com/v1/MossoCloudFS_bfe4a309-40cf-49b8-acd0-d15f48vdwds3","tenantId": "MossoCloudFS_bfe4a309-40cf-49b8-acd0-d15f486e82f3"}],"type": "object-store","name": "cloudFiles"}]
>>> data[0]["endpoints"][0]["publicURL"]
'https://storage101.lon3.clouddrive.com/v1/MossoCloudFS_bfe4a309-40cf-49b8-acd0-d15f4865542f3'
```